# Importing SVG files dynamically in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack, import, next.js

I am trying to dynamically import the SVG files that we use to increase performance. Right now we use static imports and because of this it adds all the `svg` files in the HTML build, even if we only need a couple per page. This increases the page loading times as the `HTML` file is bigger and therefor the downloading and reading of the `HTML` file takes longer then necessary.

With the current setup the page first loads but then shows a blank screen. The reason it does this is because it first loads the `<span/>` while it's loading and then replaces it with the `svg`, but since the import doesn't go well it crashes and shows a blank screen instead.

The project is an NextJS project, running with Webpack. This is the code I use to import the `SVG` files:

```
export const Chevron = dynamic(
  () => import('./Icons/chevron.svg'), 
    {
      loading: () => <span/>,
      ssr: false,
    }
  )
```

Below here you'll find the error I'm getting. Notice the `<` before and `/>` behind it, which seems to indicate it's trying to parse the `base64` string to a `JSX.Element`.

```
Warning: <data:image/svg+xml;base64,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 /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.
```

Here is my next configuration:

```
  const withFonts = require('next-fonts');
  const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules');

  module.exports = withTM(
    withFonts({
      useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false,
      enableSvg: true,
      webpack(config) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          test: /\.svg$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: '@svgr/webpack',
              options: {
                svgoConfig: {
                  plugins: {
                    removeViewBox: false,
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        });

        return config;
      },
      assetPrefix: '/_react',
      transpileModules: [
        'swiper',
        'dom7',
        'query-string',
        'strict-uri-encode',
        'split-on-first',
        'set-harmonic-interval',
      ],
    }),
  );
```

Comment: Why not simply use it like this ```import foo from 'path/to/foo.svg'; import Image from 'next/image'; ... <Image src={foo} />``` Also please add your webpack/next configuration and version to the question. What you are experiencing is not the default behavior.

Comment: @brc-dd I edited my question with the answers your requested

Comment: `next/dynamic` is used to import React components, but you're trying to import an SVG. Try creating a component that renders the SVG and then dynamically import that component instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **next-images** to import your SVG files, you will need to use them as plain images. If you prefer to import SVGs as React components, and you still want to use next-images to import other images, then you should customize your configuration to omit the directory where you keep your SVGs and use either **SVGR** or **babel-plugin-react-svg** for your SVG files.

```
// next.config.js
const path = require('path');
const withImages = require('next-images');

module.exports = withImages({
  exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/svg'),
  webpack(config, options) {
    return config
  }
})
```